# How can I escape bash commands in a bash alias

Tags: bash, alias

I want to create an alias that will use bash commands like pwd. Like 
`alias myalias="myprogram $(pwd)"`. 
But defined like this the alias will be evaluated when the alias is loaded and not when I run my alias. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I'm sorry your question doesn't seem very clear, what do you mean by "the alias will be evaluated with the alias and not when I run my alias"? what do you want to happen?

Comment: I edited. I meant that for example here the `$(pwd)` will be evaluated when the alias is loaded so that my alias will actually be `"myprogram /my/home"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply escape with `\`:

```
alias myalias="myprogram \$(pwd)"
```

This results in:

```
 $ alias myalias
 alias myalias='myprogram $(pwd)'
```

and `$(pwd)` gets evaluated when you run `myalias`.